# Not able to execute remote poweshell script in windows server 2016 unattended installation

Tags: windows, powershell, samba, windows-server-2016, unattended

I am trying to create *unattended.xml* file for windows server 2016 unattended installation where in after installing windows it should execute one powershell script located on remote samba share.

I am using following command to run powershell script stored in samba share:

```
cmd.exe /c "ECHO R | powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \\192.168.137.131\install\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
```

The Unattended installation process works well but *ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1* script execution fails with error:

```
The argument '\\192.168.137.131\install\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
```

**The same command executes successfully when I run it manually.**

Relevant portion of unattended.xml file:

```
<settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Credentials>
                        <Username>Administrator</Username>
                        <Password>Devops@123</Password>
                    </Credentials>
                    <Path>cmd.exe /c "ECHO R | powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \\192.168.137.131\install\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 > c:\pss.txt"</Path>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Description>Execute ansible script</Description>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
```

Can somebody tell me what should I add in my unattended.xml to make it working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I suspect from the docs that the Path item is *accessed* using the credentials, but not *run as*. Broadly the docs say that `RunSynchronousCommand` during specialize runs in a system context, whereas an `AuditUser` would run as the user.  It looks like that requires an administrator AutoLogon.  I'm referring to the docs at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-deployment-runsynchronous-runsynchronouscommand-credentials, and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722343(v=ws.10).aspx.

Comment: You might also check event logs at the target side to see if there were any accesses rejected.  If my theory is right, you may see a machine account access that didn't have permission to the share/file.  You could simply grant permissions to the share & file to the machine.  Are you joining the machine to the domain during the unattend?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore No, I am not joining to any domain during unattended installation.

Comment: Probably the easiest option then, if my theory is correct, would be to do two things: Try outputting `whoami` in your script to verify.  Then explicitly map a drive via either `net use` or `new-psdrive` with the explicit credentials you specified in the unattend.  Do note that these creds will be left behind in clear text in the script.

Comment: Now I am able to execute that script in Audit mode, but problem with this approach is: It ignores rest of the settings(Administrator password, EULA) in OOBE pass while entering in Audit mode. I have created seprate thread for that. https://superuser.com/questions/1226053/note-able-to-set-administrator-password-in-oobe-pass-after-returning-from-audit

Comment: I'd still recommend trying to explicitly map the credentials with `net use` or `new-psdrive`, but if you've got what you need for this question - I can put it up as answer and we can close it out.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer so other folks know it's handled.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs it seems the Path item is *accessed* using the provided credentials, but not *run as*. Broadly it says that `RunSynchronousCommand` during `Specialize` runs in a system context, whereas an `AuditUser` would run as the user.

Some options:

- During `Specialize`, map a drive with explicit credentials to the remote share using `net use` or `New-PSDrive`
- Put your commands in the `AuditUser`.  In the comments by the OP, it's mentioned this had other issues.
- Create an Administrator AutoLogon, and run your commands in a SetupComplete.cmd

I'm referring to the docs at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-deployment-runsynchronous-runsynchronouscommand-credentials, and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722343(v=ws.10).aspx